# ArcGIS : You do not have permissions to use this resource. (Error Code: 401)

Tags: arcgis-python-api

I am trying to query Demographic data using ArcGIS Python API and the following is my code to do the same.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.geoenrichment import Country, enrich, BufferStudyArea

gis = GIS("https://www.arcgis.com",myusername, mypass)

prt = Country.get('PRT')
df_prt = prt.data_collections

enrich(study_areas=[{'address':{'City':'Mafra'}}], data_collections=['PopulationTotals'])
```

And, on running the last line, I get the following error :

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-f4e6881f3364> in <module>()
----> 1 enrich(study_areas=[{'address':{'City':'Mafra'}}], data_collections=['PopulationTotals'])

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/arcgis/gis/_impl/_con/_connection.py in _handle_json_error(self, error, errorcode)
    534 
    535         errormessage = errormessage + "\n(Error Code: " + str(errorcode) +")"
--> 536         raise Exception(errormessage)
    537     #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    538     def post(self,

Exception: You do not have permissions to use this resource.
(Error Code: 401)
```

I am using ArcGIS for the first time, and I'm not sure what is causing the problem. I only followed the documentation.

What is the problem and how can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your account is not authorized for **geoenrichment**. You can read more about the [required licensing](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geoenrichment/api-reference/accessing-the-service.htm). This [topic lists which roles](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/roles.htm#USER_TYPES) can use geoenrichment.

The "fix" will be to ask your ArcGIS Online Administrator to check your account permissions. If your Org has these provisions, they'll need to assign your account to a proper role.